# Should a column referencing a group member have its foreign key directly point to the user or add an id to M2M table which represents users in a group

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a many-to-many table in a database which contains a column referencing members of a group as well as a column referencing an event.

I'm questioning whether I should set the column referencing the group member to reference the main user entry in the users table or instead add a primary key to a groups_users many-to-many table and reference the user_id there so that when the user is removed from the group then they are automatically removed from the event with ON DELETE CASCADE instead of having to manually remove them with a seperate query.

From what I know, the pros and cons for directly referencing the user are as such:

Pros:

```
Less data used up by an auto incrementing id for members of groups
```

Cons:

```
Have to manually remove users from events with a seperate query
```

The pros and cons for the other approach are a reverse of the first approach.

users table example:

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | User 1 |
| 1002 | User 2 |

groups table example:

| id | name | owner_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Group 1 | 1001 |
| 2002 | Group 2 | 1001 |

groups_users table example:

| id (only if referencing members of group rather than users directly) | user_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3001 | 1001 | 2001 |
| 3002 | 1001 | 2002 |
| 3003 | 1002 | 2001 |

events table example:

| id | group_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4001 | 2001 | Event 1 |
| 4002 | 2002 | Event 2 |

events_users table example:

| user_id / group_member_id | event_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1002 / 3003 | 4001 |
| 1001 / 3001 | 4002 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not add an artificial primary key `id` to the `groups_users` table. The natural key consisting of `(group_id, user_id)` is perfectly fine as primary key.

Concerning the question whether `events_users` should have a foreign key to `users` or to `groups_users`, ask yourself the question: is it the group membership of a user or the user itself that is related to an event? For example, if I am in two groups, could I be related to an event twice? The answer to these questions will tell you how to model this. From my point of view, a the foreign key should be to the user, but then you know the situation better.